# Position of html header navbar and main

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I wonder if anyone can help me. I am learning html, css and bootstrap. I want to make a template for my pages. This will include a top header, a side navigation bar and a main section.  However, I cannot position the sections properly. The side navbar displays in the top right corner and not bellow the header. The main text displays under the side navigation bar.  I have tried a few bootstrap classes and putting the sections in rows and columns with no luck. I have also tried to implement a few related answers from here. Thanks so much for your help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>


<body>
    <div class="wrapper align-items: stretch">
        <!-- top navigation bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white fixed-top border-primary border-bottom border-5">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <img src="/images/favicon.png" class="rounded float-start" height="45" alt="">
                <a class="navbar-brand me-auto ms-lg-0 ps-3">
                    <h5 class="home_text">Casa Coco </h5>
                </a>
            </div>
        </nav>
        <!-- top navigation bar end-->

        <!-- sidebar -->
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 bg-primary sidebar nopadding" style="width: 3.5rem">

            <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-flush flex-column mt-1 text-center">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link active py-3 bg-primary" aria-current="page" title="Home"
                        data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right">
                        <i class="bi bi-house-door "></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link active py-3 bg-primary" aria-current="page" title="Dashboard"
                        data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right">
                        <i class="bi bi-speedometer2"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <!-- sidebar end-->

        <div id="content">
            <main class="mt-5 pt-3">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem mollitia voluptatibus excepturi
                temporibus
                magnam ducimus perspiciatis, quibusdam deserunt vitae maiores doloribus voluptas porro cum, distinctio
                officia,
                natus quod explicabo eum?
            </main>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" />
    <script src="./js/jquery-3.5.1.js" />
    <script src="./js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" />
    <script src="./js/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.js" />
    <script src="./js/script.js" />


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: did you try overriding your bootstrap with some css properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was created using bootstrap 5.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Bootstrap Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap5.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap-icons.css">
</head>


<body>
    <div class="wrapper align-items: stretch">
    
        <!-- top navigation bar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white fixed-top border-primary border-bottom border-5">
        
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <img src="/images/favicon.png" class="rounded float-start" height="45" alt="">
                
                <a class="navbar-brand me-auto ms-lg-0 ps-3">
                    <h5 class="home_text">Casa Coco </h5>
                </a>
                <!-- top nav bar begin -->
                <div class="d-flex">
                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-flush flex-row mt-1 text-center">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link active py-3 bg-primary" aria-current="page" title="Home"
                        data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right">
                        <i class="bi bi-house-door "></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link active py-3 bg-primary" aria-current="page" title="Dashboard"
                        data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="right">
                        <i class="bi bi-speedometer2"></i>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
                </div>
                <!-- top navigation bar end-->
            </div>
        </nav>
       </div> 
       
     <div id="content" class="container">
            <main style="margin-top:6rem !important">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Exercitationem mollitia voluptatibus excepturi
                temporibus
                magnam ducimus perspiciatis, quibusdam deserunt vitae maiores doloribus voluptas porro cum, distinctio
                officia,
                natus quod explicabo eum?
            </main>
        </div>   

        




</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @Rishni, This is looking good!  However, when I add a sidebar. The text is displayed under it. :-(   I am adding the sidebar inside the wrapper.